# How big does a natural gas compressor station have to be, so as its possible explosion to produce power equal to that of a nuclear bomb

Tags: soft-question, power, explosions

I live in Greece and a natural gas compressor station is going to be constructed within a radius of 3km. That got me wondered. Can a possible explosion produce equal power with the little boy, the nuclear bomb that was used against Japan in 1945?

Comment: Little boy had a yield of 16 kT of TNT. The largest artificial non-nuclear detonation on record had a yield of 7 kT. You don't have to worry, that compressor station, if it blows, won't be anywhere near the size of an atomic bomb

Comment: It not about worries...It was just a train of thought.

Comment: http://npaper-wehaa.com/clevescene/2014/10/15/#?article=2354571